# ¿Cómo imprimir la suma de los terminos de esta serie?

Tags: java

El enunciado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se resuelve usando solo `if else` o `switch` y `for`.
Quisiera que me digan cómo se debe hacer para que el problema se resuelva.

Aquí dejo un poco de lo que he avanzado:

```
Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
int n, k = 1, r = 0;
int i;
int accumulator, accu = 0;

System.out.println("Ingresar Cantidad de Números: ");
n = SC.nextInt();
int[] quantity = new int[n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Digite un valor:");
    quantity[i] = SC.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("\nLos Números de la operacion son:");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("N= " + ((i - i) + 1) + " ==> " +quantity[i] + "   ==> S= ");
}
```

Comment: Sospecho que **no** te están diciendo que **recibas** la serie sino que debes recibir un único N, calcular los N términos de la misma en tu algoritmo y entregar la suma. Así pues, debes reescribir tu programa para ello.

Comment: Ashaaa, ya capté, entonces reescribiré el código, gracias.

Comment: Divide el número recibido entre 2, y si no es un número exacto redondea hacia arriba. (2.5-->3). Si el número recibido es impar, déjalo como está. Ese será el número de la suma de la serie. Si el número recibido es par, al resultado de la división y redondeo ponle el signo -. Listo.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con Alfabravo. Seguramente, solo te dan la N, puesto que es lo único necesario. Eso tiene varias repercusiones:

- No hace falta ningún array
- No hace falta introducir la secuencia de números, puesto que el programa tan solo va a servir para esa secuencia en concreto.

La solución es sencilla:

```
public static boolean es_par(int x) {
    return (x % 2 == 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingresar Cantidad de Números: ");
    int n = SC.nextInt();
    String out = "La serie está vacía."; 
    if (n > 0) { 
        out = "La serie que se pide es: 1 ";
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            if (es_par(i)) out = out + "+";
            else out = out + "-";
            out = out + " " +  i;
        }
    }
    out = out + "\n";
    out = out + "Y el valor resultante es ";
    if (es_par(n)) out = out + " -" + n/2;
    else out = out + " " + (n+1)/2;
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo que se me ocurre fue hacerlo asi solo que yo lo hice en c#

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Susesion susesion = new Susesion();
            int N_Limite;
            Console.WriteLine("Hasta que numero sera la sucesion?");
            N_Limite = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            susesion.Susecion(N_Limite);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    public class Susesion
    {
        public int Acomulador = 1;
        public void Susecion(int N_limite)
        {
            for (int index = 2; index <= N_limite+1; index++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("N="+(index-1) + " ==> " + Acomulador);        
               if (index % 2 != 0)
               {
                   Acomulador=Acomulador + index;
               }else{
                      Acomulador = Acomulador - index;
                    }
               }
            }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

De acuerdo a lo que planteas en tu ejercicio esta seria una posible solución:

```java
String sumstr = "";
    int accu = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int[] quantity = new int[]{1, -2, 3, -4,5 ,-6,7,-8};
    for (int ele: quantity) {
        accu+=ele;
        if(sumstr.equals("")){
            sumstr += String.valueOf(ele);
        }else{
            if(!(ele<0)){
                sumstr += " + "+String.valueOf(ele);
        }else{
            sumstr += " "+String.valueOf(ele);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("N="+i+" ==> " +sumstr + "   ==> S= "+String.valueOf(accu));
    i++;
}
```

Al ejecutar el programa la salida que genera es:

```
N=1 ==> 1   ==> S= 1
N=2 ==> 1 -2   ==> S= -1
N=3 ==> 1 -2 + 3   ==> S= 2
N=4 ==> 1 -2 + 3 -4   ==> S= -2
N=5 ==> 1 -2 + 3 -4 + 5   ==> S= 3
N=6 ==> 1 -2 + 3 -4 + 5 -6   ==> S= -3
N=7 ==> 1 -2 + 3 -4 + 5 -6 + 7   ==> S= 4
N=8 ==> 1 -2 + 3 -4 + 5 -6 + 7 -8   ==> S= -4
```

En la variable `accu` guardamos la sumataria de cada elemento y la mantenemos mientras se recorra el array.

En la variable `sumstr` guardamos la cadena de valores que se van operando de los cuales sale el resultado acumulado.

En `i` simplemente guardamos el número de vueltas que hemos dado en el arreglo para así poder definir que número es el que estamos operando en cada vuelta.

Lo demás solo son validaciones básicas, que comprueban cuando agregar el signo `+` y cuando no es necesario.